# Custom UIButton fires IBAction once, then never again

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, uibutton

I have a custom UIButton called RippleButton declared like so

```
public class RippleButton: UIButton
```

Basically it creates a ripple effect when touched. I'm using this custom button with the following IBAction

```
@IBAction func toggleMic() {
    if isMicrophoneOn {
        print("Stopped recording")
        micIcon.image = UIImage(named: "mic_off")
        micLabel.text = "Start Recording"
    } else {
        print("Started recording")
        micIcon.image = UIImage(named: "mic_on")
        micLabel.text = "End Recording"
    }

    isMicrophoneOn = !isMicrophoneOn
}
```

The action is assigned to the button through the design editor for the Touch Up Inside event.

My RippleButton overrides touchesBegan like so

```
override public func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
    ripple.animate(sender: self, location: touches.first!.location(in: self))
}
```

When I touch the button the first time it fires the IBAction and plays my animation from my class Ripple

```
func animate(sender: UIView, location: CGPoint){        
    ripple?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1, y: 1)
    let size = Double(sender.bounds.width) > Double(sender.bounds.height) ? sender.bounds.width : sender.bounds.height
    ripple?.frame = CGRect(x: location.x - size / 2, y: location.y - size / 2, width: size, height: size)
    ripple?.layer.cornerRadius = size / 2.0
    ripple?.alpha = CGFloat(opacity)
    ripple?.backgroundColor = color
    ripple?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 0, y: 0)
    container?.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: sender.frame.size.width, height: sender.frame.size.height)
    container?.layer.cornerRadius = sender.layer.cornerRadius
    container?.clipsToBounds = true

    UIView.animate(withDuration: TimeInterval(speed),
                   delay: 0.0,
                   options: .curveEaseOut,
                   animations: {
                    self.ripple?.transform = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 2.5, y: 2.5)
                    self.ripple?.alpha = 0.0
    })
}
```

`ripple` is a subview added to `container`, `container` is a view added to `RippleButton`

When I touch it after that first touch the animation plays, but the IBAction does not fire. Why does it fire once, then never again?

Comment: Instead of overriding `touchesBegan`, why not just hook up the `touchDown` event in interface builder?

Comment: Because I don't want to have to do that for all buttons that use this class. Since I plan on using this class in multiple places, there would be a lot of duplicated effort wiring up `touchDown` in the IB every time I implement this class.

Comment: If you just use `UIButton` does it work?

Comment: did you try calling `super.touchesBegan` after `ripple.annimation`, the button have a lot of magic going on

Comment: @Alistra yes, the default UIButton works fine when calling the IBAction

Comment: @sken3r yes, I tried changing the order, but noting happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say that "ripple is a subview added to container, container is a view added to RippleButton"... are you removing that container after the "ripple" effect? Maybe that's getting the touch event.

Comment: This was the issue. I was adding the container to fill the button which was then intercepting the touch. By adding `container?.isUserInteractionEnabled = false` I was able to get things working as intended.

Answer (score 0):

The action is triggered by default in touchesEnded by calling self.sendActionsForControlEvents. Try to override touchesEnded and touchesCancelled (with super call) and set a breakpoint in both. Maybe the event will be cancelled the second time. In that case your animation interfere with the internal button state implementation somehow. Thats hard to fix because the UIButton is a blackbox and even worse it's internal implementation may change. Then you should derive from UIControl instead.

Take a look into: [4 different ways to handle tap](http://www.uiwithcocoa.io/4-different-ways-to-handle-taps-on-UIViews/)

Comment: Unfortunately, this link is broken.